# Get Recent and Latest Value From EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a query and couldn't find it on the web in my scenario.

I want to get the most recent typed text(before the user starts changing)
and furthermore, I want to get this text only when the user starts changing the text and the latest i.e when the user stops typing in the edit text.

**Example:**

**Initial Value** in the Editext: 10

**Latest Value** in the EditText: 150 (after the user makes some change)

How can I get both these values?

I have a table of edit texts and I won't be getting the value of edit text on a button click instead when a value in an edit text changes I would be updating the total in a textview.

Value(input from edittext) is some quantity of a product in my case

```
editTextWeight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "previous: " + charSequence.toString()
                                + " start: " + start
                                + " count: " + count
                                + " after: " + after);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
                        String text = editTextWeight.getText().toString();

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                            int newVal = Integer.parseInt(text);
                            int prevVal = Integer.parseInt(tvWeightCols.get(finalI).getText().toString());
                            Log.d(TAG, "new: " + charSequence.toString()
                                    + " start: " + start
                                    + " count: " + count
                                    + " after: " + after);


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: `I want to get the most recent typed text(before the user starts changing)` this would just be editText.getText.toString, wouldn't it ? unless i'm misunderstanding, you could just use that to get the text and save that into a variable, for the rest you could probably just use a textwatcher, then compare the two variables

Comment: You are right. I just made an edit I only want to get the value when the user starts changing a value in the edit text. Let's say he types in or just clicks an editText

Comment: I have a table of edit texts and I won't be getting the value of edit text on a button click instead when a value in an edit text changes I would be updating the total in a textview.

Value(input from edittext) is some quantity of a product in my case

Comment: Or is there a way that I can get the value from editText when beforeTextChange() is called first time?